# MSQL query for fetching data from three tables

Tags: mysql

I have got three tables as follows

- **achievement**
  id, emp_id,area,dat
- **calls_per_day**
  id, emp_id,noofcalls, hotcalls, hotleads, dat
- **sales_statistics_master**
  id,emp_id, target, commitment,mnth, yrs

Now I want to extract the data of the employee from the above three tables about his achievement, noofcalls, hotcalls,hotleads perday against the monthly target and commitment.

I am using the following query.

```
SELECT  a.area, s.target,s.commitment,c.noofcalls,c.hotcalls,c.hotleads 
FROM   achievement as a, sales_statistics_master as s, calls_per_day as c 
WHERE  a.dat=CURDATE() AND 
       c.dat=CURDATE() AND 
       s.yrs= year(now()) AND 
       a.emp_id=s.emp_id AND
       a.emp_id=c.emp_id
```

Comment: Your question isn't fitting SO requirements... before it gets closed though, you should read about joins.

Comment: Thanks, but I know about joins but still i am unable to fetch the data from the table. I really need some help on this one.

Comment: You tried on your own, that's great. However, you should mention what results you are getting in your question. If there are exception/error statements, etc. copy them explicitly in your question.

I am guessing that in this case your query returned nothing?

Comment: Without a sample of the data you would expect this query to return, and what results are *actually* being returned, there's no way to answer this question. The problem could be any number of things.

Answer (score 0):

Use a join using(field).

```
select a.area, s.target,s.commitment,c.noofcalls,c.hotcalls,c.hotleads from
achievement as a join
sales_statistics_master as s using(emp_id) join
calls_per_day as c using(emp_id)
where a.dat=CURDATE() AND c.dat=CURDATE() AND s.yrs= year(now())
```

Comment: Congratulations. I hope their tele-sales people call you lots and lots. :-(

Comment: Hi Joscul  the query that you have wrote is similar to mine it is not giving any errors but it is not returning any results either, all it us returning is empty row, please help me out!!!